# How to install VS.NET 2010 without Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, uninstallation

Since we don't use and don't plan to use TFS, it would be nice to not install Team Explorer VS.NET addon and not see any references to it.

However this is no TFS option in customized install.

Is there some way to install plain-vanilla VS.NET 2010 without it?
Or maybe there is some kind of TFS uninstaller?

Comment: Please use the `visual-studio-2010` tag, not `vs2010`.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to uninstall it? Why not just ignore it?

Comment: TFS as an addon occupies system resources, screen real estate, takes time to load...

Comment: @LexL TFS does not take up any resources, well minimal (I assume) resources if you have another default provider selected. I assume as a devloper with 2K10 you are rolling 4GB of ram, half a terabyte of HD and a dual or quad core, who gives a shit if it takes up some of the "valuable resources"...not to be a dick, but really, who cares.

Comment: Like any VS plugin, Team Explorer is loaded on demand.  If you don't use it, it won't take up any resources.  You could probably uninstall it by hacking around in the registry but that won't be supported.  Put it this way: which IDE features would you like to see cut in order for the VS team to expand their installation test matrix instead?

Comment: I just opened the vs_setup.msi in Orca to see what dependencies TeamExplorer_enu component has. You'll be surprised. There are only two assemblies, that are used by some other VS.NET components.

So I wrote a program, that loads MSI-file, removes all files & registry entries, that TeamExplorer creates. 

Now I have vanilla VS2010 Ultimate installation. The link "Connect to TFS Server" on the start page now also disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written utility to surgically clean up TFS Team Explorer related stuff.

Hosted on CodePlex:

http://tfsremover.codeplex.com/

Feel free to give it a try. Works perfect on my VS.NET 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

"Unfortunately, no. In 2010, Team Explorer components are baked into VS and can't be removed independently of removing of VS."

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonba/archive/2010/02/11/team-explorer-is-included-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: Knowning that TFS integration is just normal VS.NET addon, there should be some way to uninstall it.

Inability to uninstall it reminds me of former well-known offensive marketing practice.

Comment: I agree with you LexL. I use Subversion myself. Would have been better if they made the "Team Foundation Server" options an optional add-on.

Answer (score 0):

sorry..

You cannot have only VS. Team explorer is installed by default when you install .NET.